# React Native Expo - Why is my proxy not working - making requests leads to TypeError: Network request failed?

Tags: node.js, react-native, axios, proxy, expo

Im trying to add a proxy in my react native expo app so I can make api requests to my backend without always specifying http://localhost:3001 during development.
Im not sure if its different with react native that in react apps and cannot find any info about it (everything is always about using react and roxy).

I added a proxy and when I make a request from my frontend I always get this type err:

```
[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: Network request failed]
```

there is nothing wrong with my code, if I type out http://localhost:3001 in my request, everything works fine. What is wrong with my proxy?

**app/client/src/setupProxy.js:**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use(
        ["/api/*",],
      /*  '/api',*/
        createProxyMiddleware({
            target: 'http://localhost:3001',
            changeOrigin: true,
        })
    );
};
```

**app/client/components/search.js**

```
...

const callApi = async () => {
        console.log("calling the test")
        const response = await fetch('http://localhost:3001/api/hello'); 
         //that without proxy would work
        
        const response = await fetch('/api/hello');
        const body = await response.json();
        if (response.status !== 200) throw Error(body.message);
        console.log("body", body)
        return body;
    };

...
 <Button title="test" onPress={callApi}>press test</Button>
...
```

my serverside code:

**app/server/index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();

module.exports = app => {    
    app.use(router.get('/api/hello', (req, res) => {
        console.log("incoming req success")
        res.send({ express: 'Hello From Express' });
    }))
};
```

Comment: Hi @juliascoding! 5 months later, did you find a solution?

Comment: yes, im using ngrok. so i when making requests to my backend in development, i dont make them to localhost but to the address provided by ngrok when running it